# Github - how can a user check their access permission (collaborator)

Tags: github, version-control, repository, user-permissions

As owner/member of a Github repository, I can see the people/team/roles, but is it possible to know what my access rights are, if I am an outside collaborator, because then the people section is not visible.

Putting it another way, if I cannot view all the members, should I presume that I am an outside collaborator? i.e. without asking the repository owner.